# Is it possible to compile/install Perl6 on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raku, rakudo, rakudo-star

I am trying to install Rakudo Star 2018.04 on a Raspberry Pi 3.

I do:

```
sudo perl Configure.pl --gen-moar --gen-nqp --prefix ~/rakudo
```

and it completes successfully.

And then I try:

```
sudo make-install
```

but it fails with:

```
The following step can take a long time, please be patient.
/home/pi/rakudo/bin/moar --libpath="blib" --libpath="/home/pi/rakudo/share/nqp/lib" --libpath="/home/pi/rakudo/share/nqp/lib" perl6.moarvm --nqp-lib=blib --setting=NULL --ll-exception --optimize=3 --target=mbc --stagestats --output=CORE.setting.moarvm gen/moar/CORE.setting
Stage start      :   0.000
Stage parse      : 459.019
Stage syntaxcheck:   0.000
Stage ast        :   0.000
Stage optimize   : Killed
Makefile:504: recipe for target 'CORE.setting.moarvm' failed
make[1]: *** [CORE.setting.moarvm] Error 137
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/rakudo-star-2018.04/rakudo'
Makefile:43: recipe for target 'rakudo/perl6-m' failed
make: *** [rakudo/perl6-m] Error 2
```

System info:

```
OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch) armv7l
Model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
Kernel: 4.14.34-v7+ 
Uptime: 62 days, 31 minutes 
Packages: 552 
Shell: bash 4.4.12 
CPU: ARMv7 rev 4 (v7l) (4) @ 1.2GHz 
Memory: 137MB / 927MB
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might try and increase the swap space, as [indicated in this answer in the RasPi SO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66918/90177). It's going to be slow, however, but once it's built, it's built for good, I guess.

Comment: Added a swap file and it worked! I should have thought to watch htop while building. I ended up using "swapspace" since Raspbian is Debian based and it was a really easy way to create a dynamic swap file. Just ```sudo apt-get install swapspace```.

Answer (score 7):

That's too little RAM. When I compile for x86_64, I need about 1400 MiB.

Try a beefier machine for arm, you can get one on [OBS](http://enwp.org/Open_Build_Service) for free.

Comment: You were right. No need for a beefier machine though, just a swap file.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Yes.

I built "Raku" Perl (2018.10) on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ this weekend.  I first installed swapspace as before.  The build took more than one hour -- I'm not sure how long it took, I ran it nohup -- but it finished and I've got Raku there now.

```
wget https://rakudo.perl6.org/downloads/star/rakudo-star-2018.10.tar.gz
tar xfz rakudo-star-2018.10.tar.gz 
cd rakudo-star-2018.10/
sudo perl Configure.pl --gen-moar --make-install --prefix ~/rakudo
sudo make
sudo nohup make install
```

**OLD RESPONSE**

I built "Raku" Perl (2018.06) on the Pi Zero W back in August.  I had to run swapspace, and the build took *hours*, but now I have Perl6 on three Rpi Zero W's.

Highlights of the build, as I remember them:

```
405  wget https://rakudo.perl6.org/downloads/star/rakudo-star-2018.06.tar.gz
407  tar xfz rakudo-star-2018.06.tar.gz 
411  cd rakudo-star-2018.06/
413  sudo perl Configure.pl --gen-moar --make-install --prefix ~/rakudo
433  sudo make
450  sudo nohup make install
```

Comment: pi@knowthingspizero:~ $ perl6 -version
This is Rakudo version 2018.11 built on MoarVM version 2018.11
implementing Perl 6.d.